# python ctypes - passing numpy array - odd output

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I'm using ctypes and I'm passing a ndarray to a c-function. 
It gives me a odd output behavior.
Heres some code:

C-Function:

```
int foo(int * foo,int N){
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    cout << "i " << i  << " "<< foo[i]  << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
bar = cdll.LoadLibrary(".../libtest.so")
N = c_int(10)
check = np.ones(10, dtype=int)
print check
bar.foo(c_int(check.ctypes.data),N)
```

Output:

```
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
i:0 out:1
i:1 out:0
i:2 out:1
i:3 out:0
i:4 out:1
i:5 out:0
i:6 out:1
i:7 out:0
i:8 out:1
i:9 out:0
```

Should be all ones right? :)

I' compiling with

```
g++ -g -c -fPIC -O0  pythagoras.cpp 
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname=libtest.so -o libtest.so  pythagoras.o
```

Anyone any ideas? I'm searching the failure now for at least 1hr and I'm having no idea what the solution is(probably something stupid)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `dtype` to a Python `int` will use a C `long`. If you're on a 64-bit platform (other than Windows), that's a 64-bit data type, which explains the interleaved 0s. You can check this by setting `dtype=np.int32` vs `dtype=np.int64`.

Secondly, `check.ctypes.data` is a Python `int` representing a C `void *` pointer. Passing it as `c_int` isn't correct. At a minimum, use `c_void_p`, and define `argtypes`:

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

bar = CDLL('.../libtest.so')
bar.foo.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_int]
```

`check.ctypes` defines the `_as_parameter_` ctypes hook, which returns an instance of `c_void_p`:

```
N = 10
check = np.ones(N, dtype=np.int32)
print check
bar.foo(check.ctypes, N)
```

You can be more specific with `check.ctypes.data_as`, or by defining a type with `np.ctypeslib.ndpointer`.

By the way, `foo` is a C++ function, not C. You must have used `extern "C"`. Otherwise the exported name would be mangled.

Comment: thanks! didnt saw that int is long int in c! im using extern "C" but didnt copied it.